# Linux Bash logoff on subsequent source executing after executing normally

Tags: bash

Below is a simple script that should use exit 1 when run normally, and return 1 when source-executed. For some reason, however, it fails to recognize source-execution on every 2nd attempt after having executed normally. It runs fine when using source-execution only, and strange enough, the problem doesn't happen when I use exit instead of exit 1. I tried various Bash versions and Linux distributions, but the problem remains. Maybe something fundamental.

```
#!/bin/bash
# testme.sh

$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo status = $?
  echo Source-execution required.
  exit 1 
else
  if [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO:-0} -ge 4 ]]; then
    iam=${BASH_SOURCE##*/}
  else
    echo Bash 4 or later required.
    return
  fi 
fi

echo done ${iam}
```

But here is what happens. When I source-execute testme.sh for the 2nd time it does logoff. It runs fine, however, when I change exit 1 to exit.

```
# . testme.sh
done testme.sh

# testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.

# . testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.
Connection to 192.168.2.102 closed.
```

The following works:

```
# . testme.sh
done testme.sh

# . testme.sh
done testme.sh

# . testme.sh
done testme.sh


# testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.

# testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.

# testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.
```

And when I change exit 1 to exit, it works too:

```
# . testme.sh
done testme.sh

# testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.

# . testme.sh
done testme.sh
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

I made a few changes. Adding the following:

```
$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)
status=$?
echo status=$status
echo SHLVL=$SHLVL
if [[ $status -ne 0 ]]; then
```

Yes, the $? was returning the value of the if clause. I tried so many things and got confused. Anyway, now we see that every 2nd sourcing after there was a normal execution with (exit 1) screws up the status of the return command. Again if I change "exit 1" to "exit" it works fine. Btw, $(return... or (return didn't make any difference.

```
# . testme.sh 
status=0
SHLVL=1
done testme.sh

# testme.sh 
status=1
SHLVL=2
Source-execution required.

# . testme.sh 
status=1
SHLVL=1
Source-execution required.
Connection to 192.168.2.102 closed.
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remove the dollar sign from `$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)`. It doesn't make a difference here, but to see the difference compare `$(echo foo)` to `(echo foo)`. This line `echo status = $?` doesn't work because the `if` itself sets the error code. You need to save the value: `(return...); err=$?; if [[ $err ... ]]; then echo "status = $err" ...`. Also, were you in a subshell for the first time you sourced the file (what was the value of `$SHLVL`?

Comment: I made a few changes, please see above. Again, it works as expected when using exit instead of exit 1. I can manage without the exit return status, but why "exit 1" screws up? I tried another script where I was checking the return command in a sub shell and the the status was alternating 0, 1, 0, 1 etc.

Comment: Me: "It doesn't make a difference here" / You: "Btw, $(return... or (return didn't make any difference." Thanks for confirming that. Did you try my `echo` example? Regardless, I see you're running `testme.sh` just like that. Is the current directory in your `PATH`? If not, what's actually running is coming from somewhere else (i.e. another copy, probably different, that works differently. To make sure that you're running it from the current directory, use `./testme.sh`. Note that this isn't true for sourcing a file. For that, the current directory is checked after looking in the `PATH` unless

Comment: ... `sourcepath` is turned off using `shopt`. What version of Bash is exhibiting this `exit 1` behavior?

Comment: I have the working directory in the PATH (./:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin) and run the script from command line. It's bash 4.4.12(1)-release. But the same issue is also happening in bash 5 and other Linux distros, I already checked. I think if you copy and paste the code and try yourself, you'll notice the same behavior.

Comment: Having the current directory in the `PATH` at all is poor security. Having it at the beginning is the worst case. After some testing I was able to determine that the subshell with `return` was not changing the exit status when it was successful (i.e. when the script is sourced). That's why moving it out of the subshell (removing the parentheses) works.

Comment: Actually, removing $(...) was not the solution, because then the script will return (exit) right away when the script was sourced and not continue with the rest of the script, i. e. won't check the bash version.

Comment: I just ***returned*** lol to say that. Here's your fix: `(return 0 >/dev/null 2>&1)`. The zero is the key. The reason is found in the documentation: "`return` [`n`] Causes  a  function  to exit with the return value specified by `n`.  If `n` is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed in the function body." That includes whatever happened before the file is sourced (in this case that consists of trying to run the file). Since your interest is only whether `return` is allowed, it doesn't matter that an argument is provided, but by providing it, the status is overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exhibited is due to how `return` works, and when sourcing a script that runs `exit` - will exit the current shell. Mixing both makes for confusing results, so I will demonstrate. To make the demonstration easier to follow, the shell's prompt is set to display bash's pid (`export PS1="\s-\v [pid:$BASHPID] $ "`).

### exit behavior

`exit` terminates the current "context"; Running a script will spawn a child process for it to run in, so `exit` will terminate the context it is running in - the child process. When sourcing a script, its contents are executed in the current context (current shell), so `exit` will actually terminate the sourcing shell:

```
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ cat ex.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit 7
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ ./ex.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $?
7
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:11] $ # <--- we are now in a subprocess shell
bash-5.1 [pid:11] $ ./ex.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:11] $ echo $?
7
bash-5.1 [pid:11] $ . ./ex.sh # <--- sourcing
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $? # <--- we are back to parent shell, exit ended subshell pid:11
7
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $
```

### return behavior

These are the relevant pieces from the man page, I emphasized the most important factor:

> `return [n]` ... If n is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed in the function body. If used outside a function, but during execution of a script by  the `.` (`source`)  command,  it causes  the shell to stop executing that script and return either n or **the exit status of the last command executed within the script** as the exit status of the script.

In this case, the "last command executed" relates to `testme.sh` (if no other command was executed in the meantime, including `echo $?`), and "within the script" relates to the current bash shell if the script is sourced. I slightly modified the original script to a. store the value of `$?`, and b. `exit` with a distinguishable exitcode (42):

```
#!/bin/bash
# testme.sh

$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)
return_returncode=$?
if [[ $return_returncode -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo status = $return_returncode
  echo Source-execution required.
  exit 42
else
  if [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO:-0} -ge 4 ]]; then
    iam=${BASH_SOURCE##*/}
  else
    echo Bash 4 or later required.
    return
  fi
fi

echo done ${iam}
```

Now to the fun part - running things. As long as the latest exitcode is 0, sourcing the script works well. Running the script also "works", as it is executed in a subshell so does not carry the latest exitcode to it:

```
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ . ./testme.sh
done testme.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ echo $?
0
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ ./testme.sh
status = 2
Source-execution required.
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ echo $?
42
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $
```

The problem happens only when sourcing the script immediately after running it. Notice the change in the `echo status =` line:

```
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ ./testme.sh
status = 2
Source-execution required.
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ . ./testme.sh
status = 42
Source-execution required.
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $? # <--- running exit from a sourced script has terminated its process, back to pid:1
42
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $
```

---

### Proposed fix

By clearing the last exitcode, the behavior will no longer depend on the last command. For minimal side-effects, I suggest using `true`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testme.sh

true # clear previous exitcode

$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo status = $?
  echo Source-execution required.
  exit 1 
else
  if [[ ${BASH_VERSINFO:-0} -ge 4 ]]; then
    iam=${BASH_SOURCE##*/}
  else
    echo Bash 4 or later required.
    return
  fi 
fi

echo done ${iam}
```

EDIT: another approach would be to explicitly set the return value `n` to 0 when testing for `return`'s functionality, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
# testme.sh

$(return 0 >/dev/null 2>&1)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
...
```

As @DennisWilliamson kindly commented, and considering the purpose of the statement, this (well, his) approach is better, as it is less "fragile" and will hold true even if additional statements are added just before checking `return`'s functionality.

Keeping the change as minimal as possible to achieve the desired result, the above code does not include other modifications or potential improvements (like storing the `$?` in a separate variable for later use). Now the results are consistent:

```
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ . ./testme.sh
done testme.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ . ./testme.sh
done testme.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ ./testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ ./testme.sh
status = 0
Source-execution required.
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ . ./testme.sh
done testme.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ . ./testme.sh
done testme.sh
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $
```

---

### Additional thought;

It may seem curious that while the exitcode was set to 42, executing the script echoes `status = 2`. The man page entry for `return` also states:

> If used outside a function and not during execution of a script by ., the return status is false.

Hypothesis: `false` is passed literally, and in this implementation - eventually to `exit`. This is an invalid value for `exit`, and invalid values will cause `exit` to return exitcode 2:

```
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:9] $ exit 72
exit
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $?
72
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:12] $ exit false
exit
bash: exit: false: numeric argument required
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $?
2
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:15] $ false
bash-5.1 [pid:15] $ echo $?
1
bash-5.1 [pid:15] $ exit $(false)
exit
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $?
1
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ bash
bash-5.1 [pid:19] $ exit foo
exit
bash: exit: foo: numeric argument required
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $ echo $?
2
bash-5.1 [pid:1] $
```

Proving this hypothesis (that what actually happens is literally `exit false`) is out-of-scope for the question, so while it might not be the actual case, it is reasonable enough to explain how `status = 2` might be echoed.

Comment: `exit false` produces the error message "bash: exit: false: numeric argument required" because `false` given that way is a literal string. Perhaps you mean `exit $(false)` which simply evaluates to `exit 1`. When the manual says "false" in this context, it means a false (non-zero) value which happens to be 2 ([source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exit.def)). See my comments attached to the question from a few hours before your answer for an evaluation and solution. Using `(return 0 >/dev/null 2>&1)` is superior to your `true` because it encapsulates the setup ...

Comment: ... for the test for source vs. run along with the override of the default return code into one operation thus keeping them from being separated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time to solve the issue and the explanation. Now I understand and learned something new about return [n] when [n] is omitted. The script works now as expected. I too prefer to use $(return 0 ...) instead of running /bin/true, though both ways work.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thank you for the comment. I wasn't confused between `exit false` and `exit $(false)`, I noted both cases in the post. I did say, however, that the reason I think 2 was returned is just a hypothesis, so I appreciate you going the extra mile inspecting the source code.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson as for the resolution, as both methods work for this case, "superior" might be a bit too strong. I do agree that your approach is better as it is "immune" to future modifications, so I added it to the post. Unfortunately, it is not possible to tag inside the post itself (and credit is due), I did my best. Cheers

Comment: I'd like to consider this resolved and move on, but I cannot mark a comment as correct. @DennisWilliamson, your comment was the first to solve the problem, but I will mark the only available answer as correct, which also includes your proposed solution. I hope that's OK.

Comment: @Dude That's fine.